# Sending a SOAP query to reactome.org with curl

Tags: web-services, soap, curl, bioinformatics

(Note: this question was cross-posted on [Biostar](http://biostar.stackexchange.com/questions/5511/accessing-reactome-org-using-soap-and-curl))

Hi all,

I'm trying to send a RPC-encoded SOAP query to [Reactome](http://biostar.stackexchange.com/questions/5511/accessing-reactome-org-using-soap-and-curl) (a biological pathways database),  using **curl**:

I want to call the remote method 
**queryPathwaysForReferenceIdentifiers** defined in http://www.reactome.org:8080/caBIOWebApp/services/caBIOService?wsdl

I created the following SOAP/XML file: soap.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema" xmlns:r="http://www.reactome.org:8080/caBIOWebApp/services/caBIOService" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:reactome="http://www.reactome.org/caBIOWebApp/schema">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<r:queryPathwaysForReferenceIdentifiers>
<r:referenceIdentifiers>
<soapenc:Array soapenc:arrayType="soapenc:string[3]">
<soapenc:string>Q9Y266</soapenc:string>
<soapenc:string>P17480</soapenc:string>
<soapenc:string>P2048</soapenc:string>
</soapenc:Array>
</r:referenceIdentifiers>
</r:queryPathwaysForReferenceIdentifiers>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

and I sent it with curl using the following command:

```
curl -d @soap.xml \
      -H "Content-Type: application/soap+xml" \
      -H 'SOAPAction: ""' \
      "http://www.reactome.org:8080/caBIOWebApp/services/caBIOService"
```

But the response is empty, whereas I expected a [result](http://www.reactome.org/cgi-bin/eventbrowser?DB=gk_current&ID=156715).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ns1:queryPathwaysForReferenceIdentifiersResponse xmlns:ns1="http://www.reactome.org:8080/caBIOWebApp/services/caBIOService" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
      <queryPathwaysForReferenceIdentifiersReturn xmlns:ns2="http://www.reactome.org/caBIOWebApp/schema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" soapenc:arrayType="ns2:Pathway[0]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array"/>
    </ns1:queryPathwaysForReferenceIdentifiersResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

is there an error in my Request ? where ?

Many thanks !

Pierre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the question was answered on Biostar: http://biostar.stackexchange.com/questions/5511